# Python Paramiko with Palo Alto firewall - not getting any info

Tags: python, paramiko

Im using python3 with Paramiko 2.10.3 on a palo alto version 9.1.10

I created this python script:

```
def connect_SSH():
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ip='10.x.x.x'
    port=22
    username='someuser'
    password='somepassword'
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(ip,port,username,password , look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    remote_conn = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
    output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
    print(output)
    remote_conn.send("\n")
    remote_conn.send("show system info\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    output = remote_conn.recv(50000)
    print(output)
connect_SSH()
```

Now I dont get any data from the palo alto, this is what i recive:

```
b'Last login: Wed Apr  6 16:43:18 2022 from 10.x.x.x\r\r\n'
b'\r\nshow system info\r\n'
```

It is just repeating the command i did with no data. i have tried more ways to run it even with

```
stdout = remote_conn.send("show system info\n")
```

and i get:

```
b'Last login: Wed Apr  6 16:53:23 2022 from 10.x.x.x\r\r\n'
17
b'show system info\r\n\r\nshow system info\r\n'
```

What am i missing?
Thanks.

EDIT:
using this gives error:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('show system info')
time.sleep(5)
print("OUT", stdout.readlines())

b'Last login: Wed Apr  6 17:05:26 2022 from 10.x.x.x\r\r\n'
OUT []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parmiko.py", line 76, in <module>
    connect_SSH()
  File "parmiko.py", line 52, in connect_SSH
    remote_conn.send("\n")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 801, in send
    return self._send(s, m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1198, in _send
    raise socket.error("Socket is closed")
OSError: Socket is closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding the right playbook: using panos_type_cmd module

```
- name: DHCP
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
       - ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/env python3
  roles:
     - role: PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Grab the credentials
    include_vars: 'firewall-secrets.yml'
  - name: Create DHCP relay on interface
    panos_type_cmd:
      ip_address: '{{ ip_address }}'
      username: '{{ username }}'
      password: '{{ password }}'
      cmd: "set"
      xpath: "/config/devices/entry[@name='localhost.localdomain']/network/dhcp/interface/entry[@name='{{ interface }}']/relay"
      element: "<ip><server><member>10.x.x.x1</member></server><enabled>yes</enabled></ip><ip><server><member>10.x.x.x2</member></server><enabled>yes</enabled></ip>"
    register: response

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ response.stdout }}"
      msg: "{{ response.stdout_xml }}"



  - name: Commit changes
    panos_commit:
         ip_address: '{{ ip_address }}'
         username: '{{ username }}'
         password: '{{ password }}'
```